# Wolfram Alpha gives an answer to a non-convergent integral

Tags: calculus, integration

When I am trying to solve the integral

$$\int_{0}^{\pi} e^{ia\cos(\theta)} \tan^{3}(\theta)d\theta$$

Wolfram Alpha gives the answer (putting query without the limits) ,

Answer: $0.5[(a^2+2)Ei(ia\cos(x))+\sec^2(x)e^{ia\cos(x)}(1+ia\cos(x))]$ [Alpha result](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20%28e%5E%28i*a*cos%28x%29%29*sin%5E3%28x%29%2Fcos%5E3%28x%29%29)

I am confused with this results, however when I put the query with limits it gives that the integral does not converge. What is the different between these two situations when the initial integral is symmetric around 0 and integration yields real part to zero while the imaginary part goes to infinity.

Comment: OK, did you notice what the real part of the integrand does near $\theta=\frac\pi2$?

Comment: @DavidK K  Yes. It goes to infinity.But the function is symmetric about $\theta=\pi/2$. So I took it as zero.Am I wrong? anyhow the the whole function is non-convergent but how comes Alpha gives an answer when I gave the query without limits

Comment: For a simple example of the same phenomenon, look at $\int_{-1}^{1}dx/x^2$.  This is not convergent due to the divergence at $x=0$, but the indefinite integral is $-1/x + C$, and so you might naively think that $\int_{-1}^{1}dx/x^2 = (-1/x)\vert_{-1}^{1}=-2$.  It's just that $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=F(b)-F(a)$ only holds if the function is defined for the whole interval $[a,b]$... it can't have singularities in there.

Comment: @mjqxxxx Thanks.What if I take the limits of $0.5[(a^2+2)Ei(ia\cos(x))+\sec^2(x)e^{ia\cos(x)}(1+ia\cos(x))]$? Would that bypass near singularity region and give rest of the integration?

Comment: I wonder if you can use the Cauchy principal value of the integral.

Comment: @David K I tried with Cauchy principal value changing the limits and taking series expansion at 0 ($\pi/2$) gives real part to 0, imaginary part to infinity.Any idea? Thanks

Comment: I don't know what the "rest of the integration" means.  The integral as written, and any definite integral of the same integrand whose region of integration includes $\pi/2$, is divergent.  If you want some other region of integration, like $[0,\pi/2-\varepsilon] \cup [\pi/2+\varepsilon, \pi]$, then you can use the result from Wolfram Alpha (for each piece).  But that's not bypassing anything, it's just a different integral; and it'll diverge when you let $\varepsilon\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: @mjqxxxx Thanks I got your point. However I tried this using Cauchy Principle value by hand I get the same result of real part going to 0 and imaginary part going to infinity. Alpha does not give me any answer when I give this query :Integrate[e^{i*cos(x)}Sin[x]^3 Sec[x]^3, {x, 0, \[Pi]}, PrincipalValue -> True]

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI, the "sec" becomes undefined at $\frac{\pi}{2}$ because $\sec(x)=\frac{1}{\cos(x)}$ and $\cos(\frac{\pi}{2})=0$

So it's like (sort of) $\frac{1}{|x|}$ you can integrate bits of it easily, but go over the origin and you're going to have some trouble.

Comment: I understood. My issue was why Alpha gives one answer when try without limits and another answer when try with limits. My main issue is solving the equation. I tried this using residue theorem and Cauchy principal value which gives infinity for imaginary value. In this case( Cauchy principal value) Alpha does not give any answer

Comment: this is a bad answer